# How do I extract information using regex

Tags: regex, powershell

Using the following code in a powershell script to pull data from a .txt file and not getting desired results using regex:

```
$PSRoot      = Split-Path -Parent -Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition

$csvContents = @()

Get-Content C:\PROJECTS\Reports\NodeReports\NU_001_20200620.txt |
?{$_ -imatch 'Client Name' -or $_ -imatch 'Windows Ver:'} | %{

if($_ -imatch 'Client Name'){       
           $Name = ([regex]::Matches($_,'\b\d+') | select value).value -join ','
           
                                
           }

if($_ -imatch 'Windows Ver:'){       
           $WinVer = ([regex]::Matches($_,'\b\d+') | select value).value -join ','
                                                      
           }
    $obj = [PSCustomObject]@{
        POSType        = $Name
        WindowsVersion = $WinVer
            
        }

        $csvContents += $obj
                
    }
 $csvContents | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation  | Set-Content -path "$PSRoot\NodeReportStatus.csv" -force
```

Example of output:

[image: Test]

No info is being pulled for **POSType (Client Name)**  and WindowsVersion (Windows Ver:) should just be pulling 6.1

Portion of .txt file:

```
Node 001 Status Report - Report Version 20200505;
Generated 2020-06-20 00:50:56;
=====================================================================;
DEV001 Windows Ver: 6.1, SerialLink Ver: 1464.056, CPU Type: NT;
DEV001 Name: 2723998POS1, ActiveName: 2723998POS1
DEV001 Time Setup: 06/20/2020   00:50:55   GMT +05:00,YES,35,Eastern Standard Time;
DEV001 Uptime: 9 days, 2 hours, 27 mins, 12.69 secs
---------------------------------------------------------------------;
DEV001 GetInfo: Client Name      P1530;
```

Comment: @Mandy8055  yes thank you!

Comment: @Mandy8055  Spoke to soon, not getting desired results however will keep using this tool you sent.

Comment: @Mandy8055  I tried your 2nd regex link no results, here is the update I used from your second link, it's possible I'm using this wrong but not getting any errors:  if($_ -imatch 'Windows Ver:'){       
           $WinVer = ([regex]::Matches($_,'/.*?DEV\d+ Windows Ver:(\d+)\.(\d+)') | select value).value -join ','
                                                      
           }

Answer (score 1):

You may try:

```
DEV\d+ Windows Ver: (\d+)\.(\d+), SerialLink Ver: (\d+)\.(\d+)
```

**Sample Powershell Commands:(You can modify your code according to your further requirement)**

```
PS C:\Path\To\MyDesktop> $input_path='C:\Path\To\MyDesktop\test.txt'
PS C:\Path\To\MyDesktop> $output_path='C:\Path\To\MyDesktop\testResult.txt'
PS C:\Path\To\MyDesktop> $regex='DEV\d+ Windows Ver: (\d+)\.(\d+), SerialLink Ver: (\d+)\.(\d+)'
PS C:\Path\To\MyDesktop> select-string -Path $input_path -Pattern $regex -AllMatches | % { "$($_.matches.groups[1]), $($_.matches.groups[2]), $($_.matches.groups[3]), $($_.matches.groups[4])" } > $output_path
```

#### Sample Output:

[image: Pictorial Representation]

Comment: hi this did work   DEV\d+ Windows Ver: (\d+)\.(\d+), SerialLink Ver: (\d+)\.(\d+)   I removed the second half because the SerialLinv Ver is not needed.  The result in the .csv file shows  'DEV001 Windows Ver:6.1'  is there a way I can remove the DEV001?  I tried editing the first portion but did not get any results

Comment: GM, thanks again for assistance.  Struggling with getting the POSType. which is line 9 in example: DEV001 GetInfo: Client Name      P1530;     Trying to get just the P1530 to populate.  this line I'm using    $ClientName = ([regex]::Matches($_,'DEV\d+ GetInfo: Client Name (\d+)(\d+)') | select value).value -join ','

Comment: Good evening!  That worked.  Thanks again for assistance.  I need to make some time and learn this tool your using.

Comment: Quick question do you know what I can use to auto size my excel spreadsheet?   I should just post this as new question.  Thanks

Comment: Absolutley Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Since you could have multiple Node Status Reports within one file, I'd use a `switch` statement to do regex matching and custom object creation.

```
$csvcontents = switch -regex -file C:\PROJECTS\Reports\NodeReports\NU_001_20200620.txt {
    'Windows Ver: ([\d\.]+)' {
        $Version = $matches.1
    }
    'Client Name\s*(.*);' {
        $Client = $matches.1
        [pscustomobject]@{POSType = $Client; WindowsVersion = $Version }
    }
}
```

Using `switch` with regex, each matching string is stored in the automatic `$matches` variable. Since we are only using one set of parentheses per match for the target string, that becomes unnamed capture group `1`. Capture group `1` can be accessed using `$matches.1`.